# Who is the guy in this picture?

Tags: game-identification

In DOS there was my favorite game, but I forgot its title. I have just seen the main hero of this game in this 404 message:

[image: 404 image]

Could you please tell me the name of the game? As I remember, it was about a captain, whose spaceship broken on the planet and you should choose the level walking on the map, open new levels and so on. He also show his Thumbs Up very interesting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Commander Keen.](http://www.3drealms.com/keen4/images/keen5title.jpg)

In case you're referring to the guy in the 404 picture displayed when clicking your link. If not, post a different link.

Comment: I loved that game.  :)

Answer (score 25):

The character is called Commander Keen, from the eponymous [Commander Keen series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_Keen).

Comment: I have to grant Ragnar since he was the first. But thank you anyway!